# Using a utf-8 record separator in pandas read_csv

Tags: python, pandas

I have a delimited file where the separation character is the [NOT character (¬)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00ac/index.htm) and I am unable to parse it using pandas - see below, the columns are not properly split.

```
test = pd.read_csv("file.csv", sep="¬", encoding="latin-1")
test.head(1)
0       1231�XXX7791�BBB9991�22999KKKK... 
test.shape
Out[128]: (7001001, 1)
```

I am using ipython 3.2.0, pandas 0.16.2, 2.7.10.final.0 on OS X Yosemite.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep='\u00AC', encoding ='utf-8', header=None, engine='python')

print(df)
```

The previous code will give me this, which is what you wanted. You just needed to call the correct UTF-8 encoding as a `sep`

```
      0        1        2          3
0  1231  XXX7791  BBB9991  22999KKKK
```

You need `engine=python` because by default `pandas` uses `engine=c` which does not support regex seperators.

From IPython

[image]

Comment: Weird - this does not seem to work here. I still get the same output as before i.e. the columns are not separated and appear as a single one.

Comment: Are you sure you're having `¬` as a separator in the file?

Comment: I've opened the file in Sublime - a text editor - and I've confirmed it. The documentation that came with the data file also states that's the case.

Comment: Let me launch it in IPython to see if that's causing a difference

Comment: Worked just fine. This is the data file that I accessed `1231¬XXX7791¬BBB9991¬22999KKKK`

Comment: This is making me think that something is wrong with the encoding of my source file - thank you for your help, I will have to dig further.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91114/discussion-between-spiros-and-leb).

Comment: I am hitting this issue with the "Unit separator", but pandas.read_csv doesn't parse the columns using sep="\ux1f", any ideas?

Comment: This question retains to the `NOT` sign, you need to ask a new question since this answer is in reply to your original.